# what is wrong with wcf [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed:

Tags: c#, json, wcf, fiddler

i created a wcf for mobile this is the code.

```
 [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(
                Method = "GET",
                UriTemplate = "CallPlans",
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            CallPlanCode CallPlancode();

[DataContract]
    public class CallPlanCode
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "cycle", Order = 0)]
        public Cycle cycle { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "callplan", Order = 1)]
        public List<CallPlan> CallPlan { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "MDList", Order = 2)]
        public List<MDList> MDList { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "HospitalList", Order = 3)]
        public List<HospitalList> HospitalList { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Cycle
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "startDate", Order = 0)]
        public string startDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "endDate", Order = 1)]
        public string endDate { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class CallPlan
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "transactionPlanID", Order = 0)]
        public string transactionPlanID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "mdcode", Order = 1)]
        public string mdcode { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "hospitalCode", Order = 2)]
        public string hospitalCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "planDate", Order = 3)]
        public string planDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "dayCycle", Order = 4)]
        public string dayCycle { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "isAlreadyPostedWithSignature", Order = 5)]
        public string isAlreadyPostedWithSignature { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "callType", Order = 6)]
        public string callType { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "transactionDayCycle", Order = 7)]
        public string transactionDayCycle { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "reasonCode", Order = 8)]
        public string reasonCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "postCallNote", Order = 9)]
        public string postCallNote { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "postCallNote", Order = 10)]
        public string preCallNote { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class MDList
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "FirstName", Order = 1)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "LastName", Order = 2)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "mdcode", Order = 3)]
        public string mdcode { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Frequency", Order = 4)]
        public string Frequency { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Specialty", Order = 5)]
        public string Specialty { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Product1", Order = 6)]
        public string Product1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Product2", Order = 7)]
        public string Product2 { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class HospitalList
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "hospitalName", Order = 1)]
        public string hospitalName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "hospitalCode", Order = 2)]
        public string hospitalCode { get; set; }
    }
public CallPlanCode CallPlancode()
        {
            CallPlanCode x = new CallPlanCode();
            Cycle a = new Cycle();
            a.startDate="123";
            a.endDate="123";

            List<CallPlan> s = new List<CallPlan>();
            s.Add(new CallPlan {transactionPlanID="a"});

            List<MDList> b = new List<MDList>();
            b.Add(new MDList { FirstName="a"});

            List<HospitalList> d = new List<HospitalList>();
            d.Add(new HospitalList { hospitalCode="a"});

            x.cycle = a;
            x.CallPlan = s;
            x.MDList = b;
            x.HospitalList = d;
            return x;
        }
```

when i run it on fiddler it displays [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes[504]

any suggestion on fixing it?

Comment: You might try sharing the `Request` that you sent, which could potentially help explain why your server failed to return anything. Are you able to hit the service with any other client?

Comment: i solved it . i had doubled the data member here:  [DataMember(Name = "postCallNote", Order = 9)]
        public string postCallNote { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "postCallNote", Order = 10)]
        public string preCallNote { get; set; }